# Can someone explain how header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') works?

Tags: php

I got my site working and every time I tested it it worked just fine but when I sent it off to friends 2 people came back indicating that my include objects weren't displaying properly and that I was getting an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

Looking it up gave the solutions of:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

and

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

I've been able to add the later to the top of my page that I wanted to incorporate into my php page and it works but when I do so the text header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); appears on the screen.

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
There are 2 items, a portfolio template and a gallery menu. Currently, without going into detail why, my gallery menu is built by exchanging out one menu for another. The menu looks like this (there are 6 like it):

```
<div id="gallery-menu">
  <a class="title" onclick="reloadMiddleWith('branding')"; >Branding</a>
  <a class="title" onclick="reloadMiddleWith('promotional')"; >Promotional</a>
  <a class="title" onclick="reloadMiddleWith('digital')"; >Digital</a>
  <a class="title" onclick="reloadMiddleWith('menu')"; >Illustration</a>
    <div class="gallery-thumbs">
      <?php include("galleries/gallery-thumbs-illustration1.php") ?>
    </div>
  <a class="title" onclick="reloadMiddleWith('display')"; >Display</a>
  <a class="title" onclick="reloadMiddleWith('print')"; >Print</a>
</div>
```

Here is the page it is added to:

```
<body class="portfolio">
  <div id="retainer-global">
    <div id="region-header">
      <div id="retainer-header">
        <?php include('header.php') ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="region-body">
      <div id="retainer-body">
        <div id="art-l">
          <?php include("artwork/" . $_GET["art"] . ".php") ?>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer">
        </div>
        <div id="gallery-l">
          <?php include("gallery-" . $_GET["menu"] . ".php") ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div id="region-footer">
      <div id="retainer-footer">
      <?php include('footer.php') ?>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is the function for it:

```
function reloadMiddleWith(menu) {
    var new_url = "gallery-" + menu + ".php";
    $('#gallery-menu').load(new_url);
}
```

2 users have gotten the error message and I cannot tell where to add the php code

Comment: Found a security breach in your site which you should fix because if someone can find the right file name they can access files you don't want them to. http://www.chrisjohndesigns.com/portfolio.php?art=../index you should add a switch/have a whitelist/add more testing to see if it is a good parameter for `$_GET['art']` and any other place you dump things into a include without validation.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time trying to build anything like this (I'm coming from a print background and teaching myself as I go). Would you be able to elaborate on that or recommend where to go to read up on how to do that?

Comment: Searching 'php switch include' in google or SO should give you a start

Answer (score 1):

The header will protect your website from being accessed by someone inside an iframe, will avoid click jacking and etc..

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get it from displaying the text?

Comment: it is just a header. It'll not be visible to the end users. What do you want?

Comment: I think I'm doing it wrong then. Here is a link to my site. At the top of the page the copy is appearing for me:
http://www.chrisjohndesigns.com/portfolio.php?art=digital-mch2013-site&menu=digital

Comment: @user1311848 can you add what code you have problem with in your question.